# I think these are almost the same meaning. Am I right? - time adverbial clause

Tags: clauses

> 1. In my first few weeks of the new project, I made a lot of mistakes.
> 2. For the first few weeks after I'd started to work on the new project, I made a lot of mistakes.
> 3. In the first few weeks, when I was new to the project, I made a lot of mistakes.

I have been asking a couple of questions related to what I'm currently asking.

So, I've made 3 sentences and I thought these are acceptable to use and almost the same meaning.

Comment: Jihoon what do you expect the answers to these questions be? They're gonna be hardly anything more useful than a bare *yes/no*. I recommend using [chat] for comprehension correctness checking. These questions are really too localized, they're hardly going to help any other learner here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes they are all acceptable; yes, they all mean the same. Well done.

Comment: Why **the** new project?

Comment: I'm no linguist, but that's the way we say it. Do you think all these sentences require the indefinite article "a", or no article at all?

Comment: I thought when you use "the new project" it should be specified for the reader which project, but as I read it can't understand which project.

Comment: @Ahmad it's very likely that the project is the topic for the discussion, so even if the audience don't know what project it is, the mystery is going to be revealed to them soon, and that project is known to the speaker anyways. I don't think indefinite articles will make the sentence unacceptable though.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M, Thank you, I can imagine one says those sentence to a colleague who knows the project, but can he see a random person and without any introduction starts with those sentences? Then I guess the first question of that person is "which project?". Or maybe the person waits until he complete his discussion? or maybe just the person ignore which project?

Comment: @Ahmad let's not get off-topic in comments. You can visit [chat] and we'll happily discuss it there. For now, let's not make this comment thread long.